# What are the contents of the default brackets.json file?

Tags: json, settings, adobe-brackets

I accidentally deleted my `brackets.json` file.

Could somebody with the Brackets Editor open it up, go to Debug, opens the settings file, and paste it into an answer?

Here is the file that Brackets generates for me:

```
{
  "fonts.fontSize": "12px",
  "fonts.fontFamily": "'SourceCodePro-Medium', ＭＳ ゴシック, 'MS Gothic', monospace",
  "linting.collapsed": true,
  "autoSavePrefs.on_save": false,
  "dragDropText": true,
}
```

Unfortunately, this causes the following message to appear every time I start the editor:

> your settings file doesn't contain a valid json file. The file will be opened so you can correct the format. You have to restart Brackets, so the changes affect brackets.

and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: …doesn't it get created automatically if it's not there?

Comment: yes some small lines are existing but not the full package and at every startup brackets says: your settingsfile doesnt contain a valid json file. The file will be opened so you can correct the format. You have to restart Brackets, so the changes affecct brackets. I dont know how to translate the last part.                                  This is whats inside of the json file : {
    "fonts.fontSize": "12px",
    "fonts.fontFamily": "'SourceCodePro-Medium', ＭＳ ゴシック, 'MS Gothic', monospace",
    "linting.collapsed": true,
    "autoSavePrefs.on_save": false,
    "dragDropText": true,

}

Comment: I have updated your question based on your comment. Please don't post code in comments; as you can see it becomes very hard to read.

Comment: JSON doesn't permit trailing commas. If you change `"dragDropText": true,` to `"dragDropText": true`, save the file, and restart Brackets does the error go away?

Comment: Thank you Chris i didnt know that i can paste code into an comment and yes now it works the error doesnt show up ;)

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, Michael. Now that we know this solves the problem I've added a proper answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON [doesn't permit trailing commas in object `members` or array `elements`](http://json.org/).

If you change `"dragDropText": true,` to `"dragDropText": true` your file will become valid JSON and your error message should go away.

Answer (score 1):

What I did and it worked was remove all references to the json file, leaving just {
}
It will create another default settings.